# NUXT webpack "$attrs is readonly","$listeners is readonly","Avoid mutating a prop directly"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

i am using NUXT and i have the following errors after installing VueFileAgent.

```
"$attrs is readonly","$listeners is readonly","Avoid mutating a prop directly"
```

I was reading and the community say that I should modify webPack, but in Nuxt I don't know how to do it

```
{
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue': path.resolve('./node_modules/vue')
        }
    },
}
```

does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix my problem by adding the following to nuxt.config

```
 build: {
    extend (config) {
      config.resolve.alias.vue = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js')
    }
  }
```

Comment: After adding this line, I am getting this issue
`[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build`